# No visa to destination country but can stay at stopover country?

Tags: check-in

Okay so I'm going to Tokyo from London and I'll be stopping over in Manila. Now my problem is, I wasn't able to get a Japanese visa. So my plan is to go to Manila instead. I'm holding a Philippine passport which I thought will be okay but then I remembered that they check the travel documents when you check-in. Because my flight is to Tokyo, will I be refused to board on the plane which is to Manila? What if I tell them that I'll be stopping in Manila and not take the Manila-Tokyo flight? Do you think there's a chance? I'm really worried so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The airline will probably not board you unless you agree to change your ticket, for which they will probably charge extra money.  If you're willing to pay the extra money, you are probably going to be fine.  But none of us can say for sure, so the only way you'll know for sure is to ask the airline.  It's probably better to do that sooner rather than later, as the fare for your new ticket is likely to be lower the earlier you rebook.